# Visual Studio How to Publish Application that uses data from an Online Database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, installation

Hi I published my desktop application on visual studio as a clickOnce installation but I seem to have problems with SQL and Entity Framework Exceptions as this is what my software uses in order to display data. Is there any other way to get around this problem ? Here is an image of what happens when the user wants to see the specific data. Mostly the Exceptions range from both SQL and Entity Frameworks. This only happens upon another computer and not mine which the Software was created on.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Probably the online database is not reachable from this computer. What online datastore are you using?

Comment: Sorry its a database on my computer using MS-SQL where all the data is stored

Comment: So its a local database, and the other computer does not have it, so its obvious that it will fail. If you need portable database then try SQL Server Compact Version

Comment: How am I able to overcome this problem ?

Comment: Or is there another installation option ?

Comment: I have added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to deploy your database with the application binaries then you can try SQL Server Compact instead of the full version of the server, which requires the server to be installed on the machine. The msdn link here will help you with the process -

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

and you can download the application from here -

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876

In short, SQL Server Compact databases files (.sdf) can be deployed along with your application and some binaries and dlls to help it work on the destination. The msdn topic will show you how to do this.

The full documentation and a good starting point is here too -

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983321(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983321%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**IMPORTANT** Entity framework has some limitations when working SQL Compact Databases, make sure you check and see that this won't be a problem for you.

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc835494(v=sql.110).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc835494%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)